# Font effect on Notes app in iOS 7

Tags: ios, iphone, ipad, ios7

Does anyone know how to replicate the subtle embedded look that the font has in the Notes app in iOS 7?

I played with shadow offsets and shadow color but couldn't seem to get it to look as nice and subtle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this

```
UIFont* font = [UIFont preferredFontForTextStyle:UIFontTextStyleHeadline];

UIColor* textColor = [UIColor blueColor];

NSDictionary *attrs = @{ NSForegroundColorAttributeName : textColor,
                            NSFontAttributeName : font,
                      NSTextEffectAttributeName : NSTextEffectLetterpressStyle};

NSAttributedString* attrString = [[NSAttributedString alloc]
                               initWithString:note.title
                                   attributes:attrs];

myTextLabel.attributedText = attrString;
```

[Letter press style ref](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/NSAttributedString_UIKit_Additions/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/c/data/NSTextEffectLetterpressStyle)